# How can i create random numbers without repeat them and with enough space between them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The method i'm using now is:

```
public void rndNumbers()
    {
        var currentValue = 90f;
        var increment = 90f / SpaceShipCount;
        for(int i=0;i<SpaceShipCount;i++) {
            randomNumbers.Add(currentValue);
            currentValue += increment;
        }
    }
```

randomNumbers is List global variable.

I'm calling this method once in the constructor.
But what i want to make is in a loop to get a random from the List each iteration but that the number won't be close to each other as much as possible.

The loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < SpaceShipCount; i++)
        {
            var o = Instantiate(Spaceship);
            o.tag = "SpaceShip";
            o.transform.SetParent(base.gameObject.transform);
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(SpaceShipSize, SpaceShipSize, SpaceShipSize);

            // get random position
            var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
            var y = Extents.y; // sphere altitude relative to terrain below
            var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);

            // now send a ray down terrain to adjust Y according terrain below
            var height = 10000.0f; // should be higher than highest terrain altitude
            var origin = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            var ray = new Ray(origin, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;
            var maxDistance = 20000.0f;
            var nameToLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");
            var layerMask = 1 << nameToLayer;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
            {
                var distance = hit.distance;
                y = height - distance + y; // adjust
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
            }

            o.transform.Rotate(0.0f,randomNumbers[i],0.0f);
            // place !
            o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }
```

And the line that i should get the random number each time:

```
o.transform.Rotate(0.0f,randomNumbers[i],0.0f);
```

But now it's just getting the numbers by order from the List without ant random.

This is the complete script for Instantiating the spaceships

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class CloneSpaceShips : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Spaceship;
    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject[] spaceships;

    // for tracking properties change
    private Vector3 _extents;
    private int _spaceshipCount;
    private float _spaceshipSize;
    private List<int> randomNumbers = new List<int> ();

    /// <summary>
    ///     How far to place spheres randomly.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 Extents;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How many spheres wanted.
    /// </summary>
    public int SpaceShipCount;
    public float SpaceShipSize;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        rndNumbers ();
        Clone();
        spaceships = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SpaceShip");
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // prevent wrong values to be entered
        Extents = new Vector3(Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.x), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.y), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.z));
        SpaceShipCount = Mathf.Max(0, SpaceShipCount);
        SpaceShipSize = Mathf.Max(0.0f, SpaceShipSize);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        Extents = new Vector3(250.0f, 20.0f, 250.0f);
        SpaceShipCount = 100;
        SpaceShipSize = 20.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    private void Clone()
    {
        if (Extents == _extents && SpaceShipCount == _spaceshipCount && Mathf.Approximately(SpaceShipSize, _spaceshipSize))
            return;

        // cleanup
        var ShipsToDestroy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SpaceShip");
        foreach (var t in ShipsToDestroy)
        {
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(t);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(t);
            }
        }

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        for (var i = 0; i < SpaceShipCount; i++)
        {
            var o = Instantiate(Spaceship);
            o.tag = "SpaceShip";
            o.transform.SetParent(base.gameObject.transform);
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(SpaceShipSize, SpaceShipSize, SpaceShipSize);

            // get random position
            var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
            var y = Extents.y; // sphere altitude relative to terrain below
            var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);

            // now send a ray down terrain to adjust Y according terrain below
            var height = 10000.0f; // should be higher than highest terrain altitude
            var origin = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            var ray = new Ray(origin, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;
            var maxDistance = 20000.0f;
            var nameToLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");
            var layerMask = 1 << nameToLayer;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
            {
                var distance = hit.distance;
                y = height - distance + y; // adjust
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
            }

            o.transform.Rotate(0.0f,randomNumbers[i],0.0f);
            // place !
            o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }

        _extents = Extents;
        _spaceshipCount = SpaceShipCount;
        _spaceshipSize = SpaceShipSize;
    }

    public void rndNumbers()
    {
        var currentValue = 90f;
        var increment = 90f / SpaceShipCount;
        for(int i=0;i<SpaceShipCount;i++) {
            randomNumbers.Add(currentValue);
            currentValue += increment;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to refine what "too close" means for your purpose. Then you can collect the random numbers that you generate in a list. Every time you generate a new random number, check it against the list to make sure that it isn't too close to the others before adding it to the list. This means that you will have to maintain the list of previously generated numbers in the generating function, or you will have to pass the list to the function when you make a call to get a new random number.

Comment: If you want control over your numbers, those are not random anymore, so I have to join @DavidBowling on this: Give a lot more details on what exactly you want to do and how exactly you want it

Comment: @Mark what i want to do is to spwn/create spaceships that each ship will face another direction. For now only on the Y axis. In another script i move the ships. But first i want to spawn them so when they will start moving each one will move another direction. So i want to make that each ship will face another direction/angle random and that it will be look as much as possible that each ship will face another direction. I don't mind if two ships will face close to the same direction but the idea is to random each ship facing direction.

Comment: You could make each ship face opposite of the center, then add a minor random angle change to each.

Comment: You could select points on different slices of a unit circle. Kinda. Or to make it more simple, have a base number (starting from 0.0f), and roll a random from start to 'x', 'n' number of times, then raise your start number and start over the loop

Comment: @Mark has a good idea. If you need 4 numbers randomly positioned, one in each of 4 intervals between 0 and 20: rnum1 =  a random number in [0, 5), rnum2 = a random number in [0, 5) + 5, rnum3 = a random number in [0, 5) + 10, and rnum4 = a random number in [0, 5) + 15. This solution allows two of the random numbers to be "close" to one another, but not three. It also guarantees that they are spread out over the desired range.